# Observer pattern IS-A Command pattern?

Tags: design-patterns

Let me show you the connection/similarity, which surprised me, between Observer Pattern and Command Pattern. The following is the Class Diagram of **Observer Pattern**:

[image]

The following is the Class Diagram of **Command Pattern**, which I have added an red arrow on it to represent there could be an inheritance relation between *Receiver* and *Invoker*:

[image: Modified UML of Command Pattern]

Here are some points worth notice:

- The idea of Observer Pattern is to accommodate every class who has implemented the ***Observer*** interface.

  - Whenever a ***Subject*** wants to release news to those ***Observer***'s, it just "Tell them to retrieve the news from him by themselves".
- On the other hand, the idea of Command Pattern is to hide the details about how each command is executed, and thus IMO also accommodate every class who has implemented the ***Command*** interface.

  - Whenever an **Invoker** wants to execute the command, he will just call `execute()` of the command.
  - Now is the point: Each command call a concrete **Receiver**, which IMO a it can also be an **Invoker** at the same time, to finish the task.
  - I can say that in **Observer Pattern**, the **ConcreteSubject**'s can be seen as an **Receiver** + **Invoker**, it has the job of **Receiver**, which is to provide the news for the **ConcreteCommand**, and the other of  Invoking the command `Update()` of those ***Observer***'s.

Correct?

Comment: This is one of the coolest questions I've ever seen on SO. Thank you @Niing, I was just wondering about this myself. https://medium.com/better-programming/react-state-of-the-state-e30e98abdb01

Answer (score 3):

The command pattern provides an abstraction for handling function pointers and closures in languages that do not directly support such features.

The observer pattern provides an event system (a subject notifying one or more listener functions of a change in state of the subject) for languages that do not directly support events.

Both use objects to provide a function pointers abstraction. There are similarities. But the one big difference between them is that the observer pattern handles calling multiple functions, whereas the command pattern handles just one.

Comment: For your last sentence: If the __Invoker__ in command pattern stores those commands, it can also handling multiple *Execution*. Appreciate all other idea.

Comment: This doesn't feel right. I think @Niing is really pointing something out here. I feel like its more the case that Command Pattern IS-A Observer Pattern, but that's probably just my thinking.

Answer (score 1):

> Observer pattern IS-A Command pattern?

This is a very poor way to think about design patterns.

Design patterns are not building blocks.  Treating them as building blocks and then looking for similarities in those building blocks may be entertaining, much like finding shapes in clouds is entertaining, but it doesn't help when building systems.

Rather, design patterns are answers -- suggested answers to design problems.  Just because two problems have similar suggested answers does not necessarily mean the problems themselves are related in any way.  The purpose of software engineering is to understand and solve the problems, not to fixate on the answers.

Comment: So how would you compare these two patterns? If design patterns are to solve design problem, then they are paradigms, and I can use them to prevent problems right? Why they're not building blocks?

Comment: I wouldn't compare these two patterns, because they address different problems. Patterns aren't building blocks because they don't define how they combine with each other.

Answer (score 0):

I Would say the difference between the two patterns is that in the command pattern you have a command object. Which is passed, may be persisted and contains all the information required to execute.

eg: `BuyProduct: Command { product, user }`

With the observer pattern you have no object and are simply forwarding generic change events

eg `CollectionChanged(List<Item> addedItems added, List<Item> removedItems)`

Comment: It feels like your description is a good one. It seems like you could say the Command Pattern is a refined version of the observer, with more capabilities (that you mention): the argument is an object, and the observed command has specific expectations.